# how to use type annotations in xtext?

Tags: xtext, type-annotation

How can I add a field like the following using the JvmModelInferrer?

```java
public final @IdInstance long id;
```

What I already have is this:

```java
members += domainId.toField('id', Long.TYPE.typeRef()) [
    visibility = JvmVisibility.PUBLIC
    final = true
]
```

which produces this java code:

```java
public final long id;
```

But I cannot figure out how to add the `IdInstance` annotation to the type.

Note: adding the annotation to the field works, but is not what I want:

```java
members += domainId.toField('id', Long.TYPE.typeRef()) [
    visibility = JvmVisibility.PUBLIC
    final = true
    annotations += 'com.tmtron.dscontrol2.qual.IdInstance'.annotationRef()
]
```

produces:

```java
@IdInstance
public final long id;
```

Comment: maybe https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443305 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506374

Comment: oh, thanks - not sure though if it's the correct bug, because it is for xtend - I would need it for xbase, right?  
Is there maybe a workaround for now: e.g. can I add an arbitrary string line to the generated code?

Comment: yes xbase does not support it so xtend does not. you may file a separate bug at https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras

Comment: no i have no idea how to cleanly fix this

Comment: for the generator have a look at jvmmodelgenerator

Comment: created [xtext-extras issue #218 add support for Java8 type annotations](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/issues/218)

Answer (score 1):

xbase does not support type annotations yet: see [xtext#218](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/issues/218)

But there is an easy way to generate what we want:

```java
JvmTypeReferenceBuilder.typeRef('@IdInstance long')
```

This will create a [JvmUnknownTypeReference](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.4/org/eclipse/xtext/common/types/JvmUnknownTypeReference.html) which just writes the provided string literally to the output (so make sure to get the imports right or use the fully qualified annotation).